# Do people speaking Cantonese tend to sound hyponasal?

Tags: phonetics

For those people coming speaking Cantonese, do they tend to sound [hyponasal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasal_voice#Hyponasal_speech), when they speak Cantonese, and speak English? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Objective hyponasality, the kind that can be measured on a sound spectrograph, is almost always the result of a physical obstruction.   http://www.asha.org/Publications/leader/2006/060207/060207c.htm

Even the speakers of languages that don't have phonemic nasal vowels speak with some nasality.  So hyponasality is noticeable, for example, even in English.  Henry Kissinger is famous for it.   So are people suffering from colds and the consequent swelling or blockage of the nasal passages.

So it's doubtful that marked hyponasality is a function of being a speaker of say, Cantonese vs. some other language.

As for whether Cantonese speakers *sound* hyponasal to a given listener, that's a subjective issue.

Comment: I don't know about "hyponasal" but it could be that Cantonese sounds nasal in comparison to Mandarin, in the same way Portuguese does in comparison to Spanish. But I haven't had much good exposure to Cantonese to judge that.

Comment: @hippietrail FYI "hyponasal" means "lacking nasal airflow", i.e. "not nasal"...

Comment: Thanks @musicallinguist. The next consideration would be whether OP knows the definition and used the correct term I suppose.

Comment: I know it. @hippietrail